# How to throw a string literal in java

Tags: exception

Is there a similar way of throwing a string literal in java than you would in c++?

In my assignment we have to convert our c++ code to java and I cannot get java to throw a string literal.

```
if (!head)
{
    if (index == 0)
        head = new Node<T>(element);
    else
        throw "Cannot add to empty list";
}
else if (index < 0 || index > size())
    throw "Invalid index";
```

How would I implement this code snippet in Java? The main function will catch our exceptions so we do not need to catch it outself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only throw something that implements [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html).  So no, you can't throw a `String`.  You would have to make something that implements throwable, then throw it.  Probably better to have it implement exception though and have your exception message be the String.

In your specific case, it looks like you are implementing some sort of data structure.  You should look at the closest data structure in the Java API and see what specific exceptions it throws in similar cases to get an idea.